# AWS Cognito over SSO without redirect url

Tags: google-oauth, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I have a Cognito user pool with IDP provider of Google. The IDP is from my client so I don't have much info about it or access to it.

From the cognito + IDP I get a "login" URL that looks like this:

```
https://<my-user-pool-url>/oauth2/authorize?identity_provide=<idp-name>&redirect_uri=<my-app-url>&response_type=TOKEN&client_id=<cognito_pool_id>
```

I don't want to redirect my user to this URL and then he will be redirected to my app, but I want to open a popup to log in with his Google IDP, get the token from the popup, and then log in to Cognito. Or alternatively, let Cognito do it automatically (open the popup).
Is there a way of doing it with AWS SDK for JS?

The only way I found to do something with a popup for the SSO is this "hack" which doesn't work because the browser blocks cross-origin access to the popup location:

```
const popup = window.open(
    '<cognito_login_url_with_redirect>',
    'popup',
    'popup=true'
  );

  const checkPopup = setInterval(() => {
    if (!popup || popup.closed) return;
    if (popup.window.location.href.includes('<my_redirect_url>')) {
      popup.close();
    }
    clearInterval(checkPopup);
    const access_token = new URLSearchParams(popup.location.search).get(
      'access_token'
    );
    console.log(access_token);
  }, 1000);
```

I don't want to use this "hack" or manage my own popup or postMessage between domains.
How can I log to Cognito with SSO and without redirect URI?

Update 1:
I managed to open a popup and send back the access token to my app, now my problem is using the access token from cognito to authenticate in the front end. I am using amazon-cognito-identity-js and aws-sdk and I need to log in with the access token and save all the tokens I will get in a cookie.
How can I do it?

```
const STORAGE = new CookieStorage({
  domain: WEB_DOMAIN,
  expires: 60,
  secure: true
});
const poolData = {
  UserPoolId: userPoolId,
  ClientId: clientId,
  Storage: STORAGE
};
const COGNITO_USER_POOL = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
const userData = {
  Username: '<my_user_name>',
  Pool: COGNITO_USER_POOL
};
const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
  Username: '<my_user_name>',
  AccessToken: accessToken
});
```

This code throws "NotAuthorizedException: User is not authorized to get auth details."

My other option was to get "code" instead of "token" and use it to get all the tokens (access, id and refresh) but I can't find how to log in and save the cookie with it (I can't just save because I need something called "LastAuthUser").
How can I log in with the access_token/other tokens and to save them in the correct cookie and COGNITO_USER_POOL.getCurrentUser()?

Comment: `I don't want to redirect my user to this URL and then he will be redirected to my app, but I want to open a popup to log in with his Google IDP, get the token from the popup, and then log in to Cognito.` - why? I don't understand the business need for this. What problem is the redirect causing you? Is the redirect the issue?

Comment: It is the requirement for the app. They rejected redirect URL multiple times.

Comment: If you're looking for it all to happen in the popup, I don't think Cognito supports that - you will have to manually use the [Google SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup_or_redirect_mode) or maybe try using https://github.com/ricokahler/oauth2-popup-flow for what you currently have.